# ui.draggable to show if confirmation is canceled.

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, show, jquery-ui-draggable

I made a quick list, where each item can be moved to a trash can. I set it so once you track it onto the trash, it hides. If you hit ok to the "confirm", then it is fully removed with remove().

The problem is, if I click cancel to the confirmation, it stays hidden (but I want it to show again, because it goes back to its old location, just as hidden instead). I tried using ui.draggable.show(), in many locations, but no luck. Any advice?

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gdze8/6/

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$( init )

function init() {
$(".contentItem").draggable({
    revert: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(event[0]).closest('.list4').length ) {
        var state = !confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")
        if (!state) {

         $(this).remove();
         bottomInfo();
     } else {
        return state;
    }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    }
});
$(".list4").droppable( {
    accept: ".contentItem",

    drop: function(event, ui) {
    ui.draggable.hide();


    return true;
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can accomplish this is to simply set the draggable to always revert, and then allowing the droppable function to handle whether it should be removed or not.  Here is the JS from your fiddle that works as I understand your question:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.contentItem').draggable({
        revert: true
    });
    jQuery('.list4').droppable({
        accept: '.contentItem',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.hide();
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
                ui.draggable.remove();
            } else {
                ui.draggable.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is your updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gdze8/11/

Edit: Not sure what bottomInfo() is, but you can absolutely call it directly below ui.draggable.remove(); if desired.

Comment: The thing is I want it to hide at first when you drag it into the box. With the way you did it, once it is in the box, it is still shown (during the popup).

Comment: Updated to hide until selection is made.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all of your confirmation functionality in the drop event on the droppable:

```
$(".contentItem").draggable({
    revert: true
});
$(".list4").droppable( {
    accept: ".contentItem",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var state = !confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")
        if (!state) {
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
            bottomInfo();
            } else {
                return state;
            }
        return true;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UGY2v/

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question. I don't think I was clear enough in the question. I want it to hide when you drag it in, but if you press cancel to the confirmation, it will comeback and show.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Upon further investigation, You shouldn't need the drop function at all.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Gdze8/12/)**

```
$(init);

function init() {
    $(".contentItem").draggable({
        revert: function (event, ui) {
            if ($(event[0]).closest('.list4').length) {
                var state = !confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
                if (!state) {

                    $(this).remove();
                    bottomInfo();
                } else {
                    return state;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
    $(".list4").droppable({
        accept: ".contentItem"
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to keep the .hide() because I want it to hide when I drag it in the trash. I only want it to show if cancel is pressed when the "confirmation" pops up.